# Querying denormalized tree data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tree data stored in Elasticsearch 7.9 with the data structure outlined below. I am trying to write a query which can give the top 10 *children* who have the most children underneath them.

---

#### Setup data

Given this example tree:

[image: example tree]

is described by the following data in ES:

```
{ "id": "A", "name": "User A" }
{ "id": "B", "name": "User B", "parents": ["A"], "parent1": "A" }
{ "id": "C", "name": "User C", "parents": ["A"], "parent1": "A" }
{ "id": "D", "name": "User D", "parents": ["A", "B"], "parent1": "B", "parent2": "A" }
{ "id": "E", "name": "User E", "parents": ["A", "B", "D"], "parent1": "D", "parent2": "B", "parent2": "A" }
```

*every field is mapping type `keyword`*

The document fields are:

- "id" - Documents id, same as _id,
- "parents" - All parents of the document or empty if its a root node
- "parent1" - The parent of the document
- "parent2" - The grand parent of the document
- "parent**N**" - The Nth great grand parent up to 5

---

#### Desired Results

I would like to find all "parents" from User A and the total `count` of children. So in this example case the results would be

```
User B - 2
User C - 0
```

---

#### Test it yourself

```
PUT test_index
PUT test_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "keyword" },
    "name": { "type": "keyword" },
    "referred_by_sub": { "type": "keyword" },
    "parents": { "type": "keyword" },
    "parent1": { "type": "keyword" },
    "parent2": { "type": "keyword" },
    "parent3": { "type": "keyword" },
    "parent4": { "type": "keyword" },
    "parent5": { "type": "keyword" }
  }
}

POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_id" : "A" } }
{ "id": "A", "name": "User A" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_id" : "B" } }
{ "id": "B", "name": "User B", "parents": ["A"], "parent1": "A" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_id" : "C" } }
{ "id": "C", "name": "User C", "parents": ["A"], "parent1": "A" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_id" : "D" } }
{ "id": "D", "name": "User D", "parents": ["A", "B"], "parent1": "B", "parent2": "A" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_id" : "E" } }
{ "id": "E", "name": "User E", "parents": ["A", "B", "D"], "parent1": "D", "parent2": "B", "parent2": "A" }
```

---

#### Final result expanded from Joe's answer

For anyone coming here in the future I like to post my final result if it differs from the accepted answer. Mine includes the resulting document source as well as an array. These were not in the requirements because I was attempting to make my question as simple as possible.

Maybe it will help someone in the future.

**Query**

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "parents": "A"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "children_counter": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.ids_vs_children = [:]; state.root_children = [:]",
        "map_script": """
          def current_id = doc['id'].value;
          if (!state.ids_vs_children.containsKey(current_id)) {
            state.ids_vs_children[current_id] = new ArrayList();
          }
          
          if(doc['parent1'].contains(params.id)) {
            state.root_children[current_id] = params._source;
          }
          
          def parents = doc['parents'];
          if (parents.size() > 0) {
            for (def p : parents) {
              if (!state.ids_vs_children[current_id].contains(p)) {
                if (!state.ids_vs_children.containsKey(p)) {
                  state.ids_vs_children[p] = new ArrayList();
                }
                state.ids_vs_children[p].add(current_id);
              }
            }
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
          def results = [];
          for (def pair : state.ids_vs_children.entrySet()) {
            def uid = pair.getKey();
            if (!state.root_children.containsKey(uid)) {
              continue;
            }
            
            def doc_map = [:];
            doc_map["doc"] = state.root_children[uid];
            doc_map["num_children"] = pair.getValue().size();
            results.add(doc_map);
          }
      
          def final_result = [:];
          final_result['count'] = results.length;
          final_result['results'] = results;
          return final_result;
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return states",
        "params": {
          "id": "A"
        }
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "took" : 9,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "children_counter" : {
      "value" : [
        {
          "count" : 2,
          "results" : [
            {
              "num_children" : 1,
              "doc" : {
                "parent1" : "A",
                "name" : "User B",
                "id" : "B",
                "parents" : [
                  "A"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "num_children" : 0,
              "doc" : {
                "parent1" : "A",
                "name" : "User C",
                "id" : "C",
                "parents" : [
                  "A"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your denormalized tree already contains everything you need for that calculation but we'll need to access other docs' parents as we traverse the children and keep track of the references so that's a perfect use case for a [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

```json
GET test_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "parents": "A"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "children_counter": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.ids_vs_children = [:];",
        "map_script": """
          def current_id = doc['id'].value;
          if (!state.ids_vs_children.containsKey(current_id)) {
            state.ids_vs_children[current_id] = new ArrayList();
          }
          
          def parents = doc['parents'];
          if (parents.size() > 0) {
            for (def p : parents) {
              if (!state.ids_vs_children[current_id].contains(p)) {
                state.ids_vs_children[p].add(current_id);
              }
            }
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
          def final_map = [:];
          for (def pair : state.ids_vs_children.entrySet()) {
            def uid = pair.getKey();
            if (params.exclude_users != null && params.exclude_users.contains(uid)) {
              continue;
            }
            
            final_map[uid] = pair.getValue().size();
          }
      
          return final_map;
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return states",
        "params": {
          "exclude_users": ["A"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```json
...
"aggregations" : {
  "children_counter" : {
    "value" : [
      {
        "B" : 2,    <--
        "C" : 0,    <--
        "D" : 1,
        "E" : 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

<s>A top-level query is strongly recommended so you don't blow your CPU up b/c scripts like this are notoriously resource-intensive.</s>
A top-level query is required to limit this to only A's children.

Tip: if you don't *too* frequently update these users, I'd advise to perform this children calculation before indexing -- you'll have to iterate *somewhere* so why not outside of ES?

Comment: Awesome yeah this works great. I agree we should probably update that data on ingestion because it doesnt change much but your code here should get by for now. Thanks much!

Comment: Sounds good. No prob, glad to help! Hey, shameless plug: I'm writing an Elasticsearch handbook. [What else would you like to learn about?](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV)